# (code correction) Read multiple files in different directions

Tags: python, numpy, file, dictionary

I have a number of files like this:
[image: see image]

Inside each folder is 3 more like this:
[image: see image]

Now inside each of these folders is a .txt file that looks like this:
[image]

For each of the .txt files I need to get the value from the 6th column in the file which I have circled in red and I am only interested in the lines that contain cope1, cope2, cope3, cope4 and cope5 at the start (highlighted in blue). Everything else can be ignored.

I can't use PANDAS so I got this code using NUMPY but when I run it the output it only reads one file instead of 10.

this is the code I'm using:

```
import os
import numpy as np

li = []

# Traverses thru the root folder 'roi_data' tree and opens .txt files.
for root, dirs, files in os.walk('roi_data'):
    for name in files:
        # Opens .txt file as numpy array and uses the second and the sixth columns.
        file_path = os.path.join(root, name)
        arr = np.loadtxt(file_path, delimiter=' ', usecols=[1, 5], dtype=str)
        
        # Filters out rows except those which contains 'cope'.
        # Adds ROI columns based on the file dir.
        arr = arr[np.char.startswith(arr[:, 0], 'stats/cope')]
        roi = np.full(fill_value=root.split("/")[-1], shape=(5, 1))
        arr = np.concatenate((roi, arr), axis=1)
        
        # Adds files path to distinguish for which file the calculation is done.
        # Appends the array to the list.
        file_path = np.full(fill_value=file_path, shape=(5, 1))
        arr = np.concatenate((arr, file_path), axis=1)
        li.append(arr)

# Concatenates all extracted arrays.
# Calculates the requested metrics and builds the result_di
combined_arr = np.array(li).reshape((-1, 4))
groups = (np.char.array(combined_arr[:, 0])
          + '_' + np.char.array(combined_arr[:, 1])).reshape((-1, 1))
combined_arr = np.concatenate((groups, combined_arr), axis=1)
result_di = dict()
for group in set(combined_arr[:, 0]):
    group_slice = combined_arr[combined_arr[:, 0] == group]
    values = (group_slice[:, 3].astype(float).mean(), 
              group_slice[:, 3].astype(np.float64).std(ddof=1),
              group_slice[:, 3].astype(np.float64).shape[0])
    result_di[group] = values

result_di =  dict(sorted(result_di.items()))
print(result_di)
```

this is part of the output:

```
{'roi_data\\01\\ffa_stats/cope1': (0.2577, nan, 1), 'roi_data\\01\\ffa_stats/cope2': (0.2311, nan, 1), 'roi_data\\01\\ffa_stats/cope3': (0.6393, nan, 1),...
```

and this is how the output should be:

```
{'ffa_stats/cope1': (0.76427, 0.36723498396046694, 10),
 'ffa_stats/cope2': (0.7036800000000001, 0.4011380360923157, 10),
 'ffa_stats/cope3': (1.0842100000000001, 0.39293685511938314, 10),
 'ffa_stats/cope4': (0.511365, 0.394306610851392, 10),
 'ffa_stats/cope5': (0.92214, 0.4897486570794361, 10),
```

I would really appreciate some help understanding what is wrong with the code.
In case it is necessary to test my code I share below a link to the files:
https://wetransfer.com/downloads/9120b0776ba711364579fc3b4c1374c520230106104247/654a21

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In `roi = np.full(fill_value=root.split("/")[-1], shape=(5, 1))` the split is done with "/" instead of "\", change it to `roi = np.full(fill_value=root.split("\\")[-1], shape=(5, 1))` and it worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

Here is another alternative using [`os.path.split`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.path.html#os.path.split) to be independent on the operating system and `itertools` [`groupby`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.groupby) for shortness:

```
import itertools
import os
import numpy as np

li = []
for root, dirs, files in os.walk('/home/steffen/Downloads/roi_data'):
    for name in files:
        prefix = os.path.split(root)[-1]
        with open(os.path.join(root, name)) as f:
            lines = f.readlines()
        li.extend([line.replace('stats/', prefix + '_stats/').split(' ')[1:6:4] for line in lines if 'cope' in line])

def calc(a):
    return a.mean(), a.std(ddof=1), a.shape[0]

{k: calc(np.array([float(e[1]) for e in g])) for k, g in itertools.groupby(sorted(li), lambda x: x[0])}
```